# How to get around the character limit on FormFields VBA passing from Access to Word

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm attempting to pass the content of fields in an Access form to a Word document, which, using the below code, does exactly what I need it to, except for one small issue with one of the fields.

```
.FormFields("txtReasonforReward").Result = Me![Reason for Reward]
```

is giving me some issues as I am hitting the character limit.

I've seen several examples on how to circumvent this, but I'm not sure how they work within my base code. I'm feeling a little inadequate in my understanding of VBA at the moment so any clear idiot-proof advice would be appreciated.

Please could someone give me a heads up on how to proceed.

```
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(***path to file***, , True)
With doc
.FormFields("txtFirstName").Result = Me![First Name]
.FormFields("txtLastName").Result = Me![Last Name]
.FormFields("txtReasonforReward").Result = Me![Reason for Reward]
.FormFields("txtCompanyValue").Result = Me![Company Value]
.FormFields("txtRequestingManager").Result = Me![Requesting Manager]
.FormFields("txtLocation").Result = Me![Location]
.FormFields("txtJobTitle").Result = Me![Job Title]
.FormFields("txtReqMgrJobTitle").Result = Me![Requesting Manager Job Title]
.FormFields("txtMonetaryValue").Result = Me![MoneyCalculated]
.FormFields("txtDesc").Result = Me![Description]
.FormFields("txtPayroll").Result = Me![Payroll Number]
.FormFields("txtGrade").Result = Me![Grade]
.FormFields("txtLocation2").Result = Me![Location]
.FormFields("txtRequestingMgr").Result = Me![Requesting Manager]
.FormFields("txtLevelofAction").Result = Me![ValueofPayment]
.FormFields("txtGemNom").Result = Me![GemNomination]
.FormFields("txtHRID").Result = Me![ID]
.FormFields("txtPeriod").Result = Me![Period]

.Visible = True
.Activate

End With

objWord.View.ReadingLayout = True
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `txtReasonforReward`? if it is `Short text` than change the datatype to `Long text` and under it change TextFormat to `RichText`.

Comment: Hi Tarun, do you mean within Access? Will this remove the issue of the character count without changing my code?

Comment: are you able to see whole text in `Reason for Reward` in Form?

Comment: `Short Text` is limited up to 255 characters. You can change it, it will not impact your code.

Comment: Joe, is it absolutely necessary to use form fields? Do you expect the user to afterward edit this information in a protected document? If not, use a `Bookmark` as the data target. A form field name is also a bookmark, so all that would be necessary is to unprotect the document and write to the bookmark...

Comment: @Tarun.P tried your suggestion to no success I'm afraid. The fields are Rich Text and set to Long.

Comment: @CindyMeister No particular reason for using formfields, other than I didn't know anything about Bookmarks! Will this lift the 255 character limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word has a number of possible objects that can be used as "data targets", of which form fields is one. Bookmarks and content controls are additional (but not the only) possibilities.

In this case, I would suggest writing the data to a `Bookmark`, since a form field is also a bookmark - the target document wouldn't need to be changed. This will avoid the 255 character limit, which is due to the form field, not to Word.

In order to write to a bookmark in a document protected as a form (which this appears to be) it is necessary to remove forms protection. This can be re-instated writing the data. It's probably a good idea to do so, as otherwise the form fields could reset, which would lose the data written to them. That, or apply the bookmark technique across the board rather than to only one data target.

```
'Add objects to the declarations
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim x As String

'Do things...

.FormFields("txtHRID").Result = Me![ID]
.FormFields("txtPeriod").Result = Me![Period]

'After writing to the form fields, add the long string of data
If doc.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
   doc.Unprotect
End If
'Get the range of the form field, based on its name
Set rng = doc.Bookmarks("txtReasonforReward").Range
'Move the starting point back one character so that the form field can be deleted. 
rng.MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
'Be sure to save this character as the deletion will remove it
x = rng.Characters.First
rng.FormFields(1).Delete
'Assign the value
rng.Text = x & Me![Reason for Reward]
'Re-instate document protection
doc.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, True
```

Comment: Hi Cindy, thanks for the assistance. Can you advise how one would go about implementing this within my existing code block?

Comment: @Joe I was on a mobile device, when I realized I needed to check my logic... I've edited the code after testing. The comments should explain how it works. Put the declarations with the other ones, then put the rest in after writing to the form fields. (Remember to remove the one that's currently causing the error, that this is replacing.)

Comment: Think I'm going wrong somewhere... 
 I've put the first two lines above my With doc section, and then the rest after my End with to no success

Comment: Before the `End With` - in the position I show after writing to form fields; I copied/pasted the last two lines from your code in order to show the position. If it's still "not working" you need to provide more information about *how* it's not working.

Comment: Apologies... didn't notice that they were the last two lines... Just to confirm, your first two lines DO NOT go within the With? I have it working with them outside...

Comment: Next question, I need the data from [Reason for Reward] to go into two separate fields within the Word document, is there an easy way to send it to two locations?

Comment: Next question should be a *new* question @Joe ... How have you been doing it up untl now? If you haven't, then definitely a new question, with all the background infornation to be able to reproduce the logic and the situation.

Comment: Hi Cindy, I was doing it before with a slightly backdoor solution: 
.FormFields("txtReasonforReward2").Result = Me![Reason for Reward]
Is there a quick way to implement this with what you've supplied?

Comment: In that case, please make it a new question as the approach used up until now (altered to fit the different field name) would also work with the proposed answer to the question of how to avoid the character limit with form fields. Different topic = different question according to site guidelines :-)